How to avoid template constraint failure in the non-selected type when using std::conditional?
I need to select between two types for a variable at compile time. One of these types have a concept requirement which is not always satisfied and that is when I want to select the other type. I am trying to achieve this with std::conditional_t, but both types to std::conditional are evaluated causing a template constraint failure.
Here's a minimal example:
#include <concepts>

template <typename T> requires std::same_as<T, int>
struct Foo {};

using MyType1 = std::conditional_t<true, int, Foo<int>>; // Compiles
using MyType2 = std::conditional_t<false, int, Foo<int>>; // Compiles
using MyType3 = std::conditional_t<true, int, Foo<double>>; // Doesn't compile (constraint fails)
using MyType4 = std::conditional_t<true, Foo<double>, int>; // Doesn't compile (constraint fails)

MyType3 and 4 both fails since Foo does not satisfies the constraint on Foo. For MyType3 I would expect it to work since the conditional selects int as the type, not Foo.
Can I achieve my goal with std::conditional or any other means?

Hint: the concept cam be incorporated into the template, like template <std::same_as<int> T>.

You might add some indirection:
template <template <typename> class C, typename T>
struct binder
{
    using type = C<T>;
};

using MyType3 = std::conditional_t<true,
                                  std::type_identity<int>,
                                  binder<Foo, double>>::type;

Demo

Jarod42's answer is good, but I also found another possible solution using template specialization which I post here for completeness sake:
#include <concepts>

template <std::same_as<int> T>
struct Foo {};

template <bool T>
struct MyConditional {
    using type = int;
};

template <>
struct MyConditional<false> {
    using type = Foo<int>;
};

using MyType3 = MyConditional<true>::type;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<MyType3, int>);

using MyType4 = MyConditional<false>::type;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<MyType4, Foo<int>>);


You no longer have Foo<double> anywhere ;-)

@Jarod42 True, but this solves the overall problem where I want either an int or a Foo based on the truth value which in my real case would be a type check. The original minimal example is not very well constructed as the Foo is a bit artificial.
